# Can't Get Google Plus to Align With Other Social Media Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-plus

I am trying to put a Google Plus One and other social media buttons inline next to each other. For some reason the Google Plus button has moves it down by a few pixel. It says there is a p tag separating them but there is no p tag in the code. The Google Plus code has it's own div tag but I don't know how to align it with the other buttons. I am using Wordpress.

Is there a better way to align these?

```
<iframe style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 52px; height: 20px;" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fjrbweddings&amp;width=100&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><iframe style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 60px; height: 20px;" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fjrbweddings.com%2Fleena-joel&amp;layout=button" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png" alt="" /></a><script src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js" async="" defer="defer" type="text/javascript"></script> <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="Check out this Wedding Video!" data-related="jrbweddings" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script>// <![CDATA[ !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs'); // ]]></script><script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async="" defer="defer"></script><div class="g-plusone" data-align="right" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></div><div align="right">Wedding Photographer: <a href="http://www.giomoralesphotography.com/">Gio Morales</a></div>
```

example of how I want it to look but need google plus:

```
<p class="split-para">
<iframe style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 52px; height: 20px;" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fjrbweddings&amp;width=100&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 60px; height: 20px;" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fjrbweddings.com%2Fleena-joel&amp;layout=button" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark">
    <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png" alt="" />
</a>
<script src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js" async="" defer="defer" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="Check out this Wedding Video!" data-related="jrbweddings" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>// 
    <![CDATA[!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');// ]]>
</script>
<span>Wedding Photographer: 
    <a href="http://www.giomoralesphotography.com/">Gio Morales</a>
</span>
```

I've found out that this jQuery code works but it disables the plug in that's on the page and the 'Wedding Photographer' text that's right justified:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> $("iframe[src='//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fjrbweddings&width=100&layout=button&action=like&show_faces=false&share=false&height=35']").unwrap();
```

Comment: If you change `<div class="g-plusone"` to `<span class="g-plusone"`, would it work?

Comment: You are a saint! And yes it worked lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-align="right" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></div>
```

to

```
<span class="g-plusone" data-align="right" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></span>
```

should work, because div is a block element while span is an inline one. Since it was a block element it was being pushed down the page a bit.